# Query, which returns data from last week / month ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

The query should return the last week of month. Today is 17/03/2020, 
should return last week of the day 09/03/2020(monday) to day 15/03/2020 (sunday)...

so next week the same thing on day 23/03/2020(monday) return last week from day (16/03/2020) to (22/03/2020)

And return first day of last month to Last day of last month

MY DB Is Oracle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`next_day()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/NEXT_DAY.html#GUID-01B2CC7A-1A64-4A74-918E-26158C9096F6):

```
select
    next_day(sysdate - 14, 'monday') start_of_last_week,
    next_day(sysdate - 7, 'sunday') end_of_last_week
from dual
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=899a88bd5b652cdb85e022c07bb367c0)**:

```
START_OF_LAST_WEEK | END_OF_LAST_WEEK
:----------------- | :---------------
09-MAR-20          | 15-MAR-20
```

If you want the start and end of last month, then:

```
select
    add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1) start_of_last_month,
    trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - 1 end_of_last_month
from dual
```

Comment: select
    next_day(sysdate - 14, 'monday') start_of_last_week,
    next_day(sysdate - 7, 'sunday') end_of_last_week
from dual


when I used it I received

01846. 00000 -  "not a valid day of the week"
*Cause:    
*Action:



select
    add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1) start_of_last_month,
    trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - 1 end_of_last_month
from dual

worked perfectly ! THANKS

Comment: @RM08 - the `next_day()` function is NLS-sensitive but unfortunately doesn't have an option to override the date language (as `to_char()` does, for example). So you have to give the day names/abbreviations in the same language you see when you query a date.

Answer (score 2):

`NEXT_DAY` is dependent on the language your database is set to. To do it independently of any language (and without relying on any strings) you can `TRUNC`ate the date to the start of the ISO 8601 week (using the `IW` format model) which will always be midnight Monday of that week:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC( sysdate, 'IW' ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY AS start_of_last_week,
       TRUNC( sysdate, 'IW' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY AS sunday_of_last_week,
       TRUNC( sysdate, 'IW' )                    AS start_of_this_week
FROM   DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

As a slight enhancement to @GMB's week query, you can avoid the NLS dependency by getting the day names in the current session's date language by getting those from any arbitrary fixed date that happens to be on the required day; e.g.:

```
alter session set nls_date_language = 'ENGLISH';

select
    to_char(date '2018-01-01', 'day') as monday,
    to_char(date '2017-12-31', 'day') as monday,
    next_day(sysdate - 14, to_char(date '2018-01-01', 'day')) start_of_last_week,
    next_day(sysdate - 7, to_char(date '2017-12-31', 'day')) end_of_last_week
from dual;

MONDAY    MONDAY    START_OF_L END_OF_LAS
--------- --------- ---------- ----------
monday    sunday    2020-03-09 2020-03-15

alter session set nls_date_language = 'FRENCH';

select
    to_char(date '2018-01-01', 'day') as monday,
    to_char(date '2017-12-31', 'day') as monday,
    next_day(sysdate - 14, to_char(date '2018-01-01', 'day')) start_of_last_week,
    next_day(sysdate - 7, to_char(date '2017-12-31', 'day')) end_of_last_week
from dual;

MONDAY   MONDAY   START_OF_L END_OF_LAS
-------- -------- ---------- ----------
lundi    dimanche 2020-03-09 2020-03-15
```

This avoids the possibility of getting an ORA-01846 "not a valid day of the week" error.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3ee5d23986adf991f5ed9c504240ec4c)